# How can I get all employees with a avg salary that are in company less than 5 years

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me , i need to write query for next case .
It is necessary to draw from the table asking the average salary of employees in the company for more than 5 years, and the average salary of employees in the company up to 5 years.

SELECT name,avg(salary) FROM employees WHERE HIREDATE < (19-july-09) AND 
HIREDATE > (19-JUL-09) ''

Is this good?

Comment: show full details and what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly not right - you're asking for employees that have been employed before 19-july-09 and also employed after 19-july-14, so no-one will fulfill both (in fact, no one will fulfil the second condition, since you won't have people you haven't hired yet in the database.

You don't say what database you are using. Also, what do you want out of this exactly? Do you want something like:

        `Avg salary of employees hired at least 5 years ago = xxxxx
        Avg salary of employees hired less than 5 years ago = yyyyy`

Just very roughly, this would look something like this (I think this syntax is MySQL compliant):

`SELECT CASE WHEN HIREDATE < '2009-07-09' then 1 else 0 END AS five_years,
               avg(salary)
        FROM employees
        GROUP BY CASE WHEN HIREDATE < '2009-07-09' then 1 else 0 END`

or alternatively, I think this might work in MySQL to avoid the constants:

`SELECT CASE WHEN HIREDATE < date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 YEAR) then 1 
               ELSE 0 END AS five_years,
               avg(salary)
        FROM employees
        GROUP BY CASE WHEN HIREDATE < date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 YEAR) then 1 
                 ELSE  0 END`

Comment: I wrote wrong year there . Yes that was the case
"Avg salary of employees hired at least 5 years ago = xxxxx Avg salary of employees hired less than 5 years ago = yyyyy"            Thank you , i will try this one .